# BASH - how to redirect output 1 and 2 to file and screen?

Tags: linux, bash

how to redirect output 1 and 2 to file and screen?

```
command 2 1 > /tmp/log and 2 1 screen
```

all output to file and screen

thank you

Comment: what is 1 and 2? stderr and stdout?

Comment: yes.. stderr and stdout

Comment: actually, @perreal, the other way around - 1 is stdout, 2 is stderr.

Answer (score 7):

The tee command directs output to both a file and the tty.

```
echo 'hi there'  2>&1 | tee outputfile
```

writes the same "hi there" to both outputfile and to the tty.
This redirects 1 and 2.

From your description try script:

```
Linux / Unix Command: script

 Command Library
NAME

script - make typescript of terminal session  
SYNOPSIS

script [-a ] [-f ] [-q ] [-t ] [file ]  
DESCRIPTION

Script makes a typescript of everything printed on your terminal. It is useful for students who need a hardcopy record of an interactive session as proof of an assignment, as the typescript file can be printed out later with lpr(1).
If the argument file is given, script saves all dialogue in file If no file name is given, the typescript is saved in the file typescript
```

Comment: Example when using nano /etc/foo 2>&1 | tee /tmp/log. File /tmp/log no read :-(

Comment: `nano` is a full-screen editor; it doesn't make a lot of sense to try to redirect its standard output to a file.

Comment: yes I know, but I do not know in advance what the command will be executed :-(

Comment: Exactly what are trying to do, please tell us. Please do not tell us how you think it should be done.  There is some lack of communication here.

Answer (score 0):

I have 1000 commands

example

```
apt-get install;
mc;
apt-get update;
echo "foo";
..
..
..
nano /etc/passwd;
ls /tmp/log;
mc;
screen
```

I need to send the result to the screen and also save into the file.

Nobody knows what will run the command.

Thank you

Comment: I'm sorry this makes very little sense.  Some commands DO NOT work with redirection.  There is a script command.  Everything you do and type and print ends up in a file.  It sounds like you want auditing.